# Angular Promises using $q.all

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, promise

I have an array of items. For each of the item in that array, I need to make an API call.

Only after all the calls for the items are finished, then only I want to proceed.

```
var itemProgress = [];
var promises = currentBatches.map(function(batch){
    HttpWrapper.send('/api/'+batch.job_id+'/progress', { "operation": 'GET' })
    .then(function(result) {
        batch.succeeded_time_pct = result.succeeded_by_time_pct; // I add one property to each of the item
        itemProgress.push(batch); // I push it to a new array
    },function(errorResponse) {
        console.log(errorResponse);
    });
});
```

Here I am trying to add a `new property` to each of the items after making `an API call for each of the items`.

And when all the calls are done, 
I want to assign `this new array to the current array`.

```
$q.all(promises).then(function(result){

    currentBatches = itemProgress;
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Why `currentBatches = migrationProgress; inside $q.all` is being evaluated **before** the topmost block gets executed for each of the items. How can I fix it?

Comment: You need a return statement inside your map call to start with. You're creating the promises, but you didn't return them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put a `return` inside the `map()` callback.

```
var itemProgress = [];
var promises = currentBatches.map(function(batch){
    // return the following promise
    return HttpWrapper.send('/api/'+batch.job_id+'/progress', { "operation": 'GET' })
    .then(function(result) {
        batch.succeeded_time_pct = result.succeeded_by_time_pct; // I add one property to each of the item
        itemProgress.push(batch); // I push it to a new array
    },function(errorResponse) {
        console.log(errorResponse);
    });
});

$q.all(promises).then(function(result){
    currentBatches = itemProgress;
});
```

This will return the promise generate by `HttpWrapper.send()` and put it as an item of the promises array. Take a look in the [map() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control): the callback should be a function that produces an element of the new array. Without the return statement the element will be `undefined`. Because of it the $q.all call is resolved immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That helped a lot apart from the superb answer. Cheers :)